# 'expression' argument of request.security function should have no side effects

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

been getting the 'expression' argument of request.security function should have no side effects when I try to run the code, I'm trying to fire alerts for multiple symbols under one alert function, I've tried multiple methods but all to no avail, tried using the close variable with upfractal and dnfractal variables nut because they're boolean I couldnt get that to work. This is the code:

```
//@version=5


// Define our title and that this script will overlay the candles.
indicator('QQQGrail', shorttitle='QQQGrail', overlay=true, max_bars_back=144)

n = input.int(title='Periods', defval=2, minval=2)
fractalBars = input.string(title='3 or 5 Bar Fractal', defval='3', options=['3', '5'])
arrayLength = input.int(title='Max nr of historical fractals', defval=20, minval=1, maxval=25)
plotActiveLines = input(title='Plot active lines', defval=true)

var upFractalArray = array.new_int(arrayLength)
var dnFractalArray = array.new_int(arrayLength)

var bool isAlertLow = na
var bool isAlertHigh = na
// Fractal Code
dnFractal = if fractalBars == '5'
    dnFractal5 = high[n - 2] < high[n] and high[n - 1] < high[n] and high[n + 1] < high[n] and high[n + 2] < high[n]
    dnFractal5
else
    if fractalBars == '3'
        dnFractal3 = high[n - 1] < high[n] and high[n + 1] < high[n]
        dnFractal3

upFractal = if fractalBars == '5'
    upFractal5 = low[n - 2] > low[n] and low[n - 1] > low[n] and low[n + 1] > low[n] and low[n + 2] > low[n]
    upFractal5
else
    if fractalBars == '3'
        upFractal3 = low[n - 1] > low[n] and low[n + 1] > low[n]
        upFractal3

// Active fractals
if dnFractal
    array.push(dnFractalArray, bar_index[n])
    array.shift(dnFractalArray)
if upFractal
    array.push(upFractalArray, bar_index[n])
    array.shift(upFractalArray)

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to array.size(dnFractalArray) - 1 by 1
        dnBarIndex = array.get(dnFractalArray, i)
        l = line.new(color=color.red, x1=dnBarIndex, y1=high[bar_index - dnBarIndex], x2=bar_index, y2=high[bar_index - dnBarIndex])
        wickFound = false
        limitCount = 0
        // Find out if we have a higher fractal
        for t = i to array.size(dnFractalArray) - 1 by 1
            nextFractalIndex = array.get(dnFractalArray, t)
            if high[bar_index - dnBarIndex] < high[bar_index - nextFractalIndex]
                limitCount := bar_index - nextFractalIndex
                break
        // Delete line if it will only hit a closed candle
        // Else plot the line up to the last wick
        for j = bar_index - dnBarIndex - 1 to limitCount by 1
            if high[bar_index - dnBarIndex] < high[j]
                if high[bar_index - dnBarIndex] < close[j]
                    if not wickFound
                        line.delete(l)
                    break
                else
                    wickFound := true
                    line.set_x2(l, bar_index - j)
        if not plotActiveLines and line.get_x2(l) == bar_index
            line.set_color(l, color.new(color.red, 100))
        // Alert condition
        isAlertHigh := line.get_x2(l) == bar_index and high[bar_index - dnBarIndex] < high
        isAlertHigh

    for i = 0 to array.size(upFractalArray) - 1 by 1
        upBarIndex = array.get(upFractalArray, i)
        l = line.new(color=color.green, x1=upBarIndex, y1=low[bar_index - upBarIndex], x2=bar_index, y2=low[bar_index - upBarIndex])
        wickFound = false
        limitCount = 0
        // Find out if we have a lower fractal
        for t = i to array.size(upFractalArray) - 1 by 1
            nextFractalIndex = array.get(upFractalArray, t)
            if low[bar_index - upBarIndex] > low[bar_index - nextFractalIndex]
                limitCount := bar_index - nextFractalIndex
                break
        // Delete line if it will only hit a closed candle
        // Else plot the line up to the last wick
        for j = bar_index - upBarIndex - 1 to limitCount by 1
            if low[bar_index - upBarIndex] > low[j]
                if low[bar_index - upBarIndex] > close[j]
                    if not wickFound
                        line.delete(l)
                    break
                else
                    wickFound := true
                    line.set_x2(l, bar_index - j)
        if not plotActiveLines and line.get_x2(l) == bar_index
            line.set_color(l, color.new(color.green, 100))
        // Alert condition
        isAlertLow := low[bar_index - upBarIndex] > low and line.get_x2(l) == bar_index
        isAlertLow

alertcondition(isAlertHigh, title='Sweep High', message='QQQ found a higher sweep')
alertcondition(isAlertLow, title='Sweep Low', message='QQQ found a lower sweep')
alertcondition(isAlertLow or isAlertHigh, title='Sweep', message='QQQ found a sweep')

plotshape(dnFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, offset=-n, color=color.new(color.red, 25))
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, offset=-n, color=color.new(color.green, 25))

checkForAlert()=>
    alertMsg = ""

    // check for sweep
    
    if isAlertLow or isAlertHigh == true
        alertMsg += str.format("Liquidity grab {0} for {1}!\n", high, syminfo.ticker)

    

           

    // any other checks needed

    alertMsg

fireAlert(ticker, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)=>
    msg = request.security(ticker, timeframe.period, checkForAlert())
    if str.length(msg) > 0
        alert(msg, freq)

fireAlert("AUDCAD")
fireAlert("AUDCHF")
fireAlert("AUDJPY")
fireAlert("AUDNZD")
fireAlert("AUDUSD")
fireAlert("CADCHF")
fireAlert("CADJPY")
fireAlert("CHFJPY")
fireAlert("EURAUD")
fireAlert("EURCAD")
fireAlert("EURCHF")
fireAlert("EURGBP")
fireAlert("EURJPY")
fireAlert("EURNZD")
fireAlert("EURUSD")
fireAlert("GBPAUD")
fireAlert("GBPCAD")
fireAlert("GBPCHF")
fireAlert("GBPJPY")
fireAlert("GBPNZD")
fireAlert("GBPUSD")
fireAlert("NZDCAD")
fireAlert("NZDCHF")
fireAlert("NZDJPY")
fireAlert("NZDUSD")
fireAlert("USDCAD")
fireAlert("USDCHF")
fireAlert("USDJPY")
fireAlert("XAUUSD")
fireAlert("US30USD")
fireAlert("NAS100USD")
fireAlert("SPX500USD")
fireAlert("GER30")
fireAlert("UK100GBP")

// more symbols here ... max 40
```

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript, you cant' use 'request.security' with a variable for the timeframe part.

You must use something like this :

```
msg = request.security(ticker, "20", your_expression)
```

see : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity)

Comment: I do not think this answer is correct. See example here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html?highlight=request%20security#request-security.
... tfInput = input.timeframe("", "", inline = "1")
[hi, lo] = request.security(symbolInput, tfInput, [high, low]) ...

Comment: @freenrg In the example you provide, the variable symbiolinput, tfinput are 'fixed' variables ( or constants). Try to use request.security with a variable that you can change and it will generate an error : you cant' use 'request.security' with a variable for the timeframe part.

Comment: I see, @G.Lebret. Thanks for clarifying that. I learned something new with your comment.